# Getting sql connection string from web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-config, connection-string

I am learning to write into a database from a textbox with the click of a button. I have specified the connection string to my NorthWind database in my `web.config` file. However I am not able to access the connection string in my code behind.

This is what I have tried.

```
protected void buttontb_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Configuration.Configuration rootwebconfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/Mohtisham");
    System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings constring;
    constring = rootwebconfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["northwindconnect"];
    SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(constring);

    sql.Open();
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Insert into categories (categoryName) values ('" + tb_database.Text + "')", sql);
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sql.Close();
}
```

I get a tooltip error for

```
SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(constring);
```

as

> *System.data.SqlClient.Sqlconnection.Sqlconnection(string) has some invalid arguments.*

I want to load the connection string from the `web.config` in `constring`

Comment: It is not related to question but writing into DB from text box cause sql injection.

Comment: @Popeye Is it? What do you suggest? Which is a better way to store user input values in a database?

Comment: Just search on google also you can refer this http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/113/Preventing-SQL-Injection-in-ASP.NET

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because the [`ConnectionStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.connectionstringsettingscollection.aspx) collection is a collection of [`ConnectionStringSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.connectionstringsettings.aspx) objects, but the [`SqlConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) constructor expects a `string` parameter. So you can't just pass in `constring` by itself.

Try this instead.

```
SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(constring.ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 12):

You can simply give a `Name` to your `ConnectionString` in `web.config` file and do this:

web.config:

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"  connectionString=YourServer"; Initial Catalog=YourDB; Integrated Security=True"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
readonly SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["northwindconnect"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggests you to create a function rather than directly access the web.config file as follow

```
    public static string GetConfigurationValue(string pstrKey)
    {
        var configurationValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[pstrKey];
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(configurationValue))
            return configurationValue;

        throw (new ApplicationException(
            "Configuration Tag is missing web.config. It should contain   <add key=\"" + pstrKey + "\" value=\"?\"/>"));

    }
```

And use this function in you application